# How can I distribute same data to multiple user with out conflicting in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I was trying to make an app with rails which have a large amount of data. It would have multiple have user. I want it to be like if one user sees a data then it will not appear to other user. I'm trying to show that in index view. Also I don't want show more than 20 data at a time. How can I do that?

My index controller is

```
def index
    @clients = Client.all
end
```

View is like:

```
 <% @clients.each_with_index do |client,index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= index+1 %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.full_name %>
        <td><%= card_client.email %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.mobile %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.profession %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.company %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.position %></td>
        <td><%= card_client.location %></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox">Pending</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox">Success</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox">Decline</td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Database is a mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to have users with a one to many relationship to clients.

You need to add a user_id column to your clients so that you can query the clients for individual users.

Run a migration with `add_reference :clients, :user, index: true`

Once you have that you can add the relationship in your model so you can do `current_user.clients.all` assuming you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

As for your question about only showing 20, you can either limit the query or have pagination. I would assume you want pagination so i would recommend this common gem [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)